# Dependency Injection to modules

Tags: python, dependency-injection, python-module

Consider a module, e.g. `some_module`, that various modules use in the same interpreter process. This module would have a single context. In order for `some_module` methods to work, it must receive a dependency injection of a class instance.

What would be a pythonic and elegant way to inject the dependency to the module?

Answer (score 3):

Use a module global.

```
import some_module
some_module.classinstance = MyClass()
```

`some_module` can have code to set up a default instance if one is not received, or just set `classinstance` to `None` and check to make sure it's set when the methods are invoked.

Answer (score 2):

IMHo opinion full fledged `Dependency Injection` with all jargon is better suited to statically typed languages like Java, in python you can accomplish that very easily e.g here is a bare bone `injection`

```
class DefaultLogger(object):
   def log(self, line):
      print line

_features = {
   'logger': DefaultLogger
   }

def set_feature(name, feature):
   _features[name] = feature

def get_feature(name):
   return _features[name]()

class Whatever(object):

   def dosomething(self):
      feature = get_feature('logger')

      for i in range(5):
         feature.log("task %s"%i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   class MyLogger(object):
      def log(sef, line):
         print "Cool",line

   set_feature('logger', MyLogger)

   Whatever().dosomething()
```

output:

```
Cool task 0
Cool task 1
Cool task 2
Cool task 3
Cool task 4
```

If you think something is missing we can add that easily, its python.

Comment: This is not dependency injection but a service locator.

Comment: @deamon May be it is none, may be it is both `get_feature('logger')` is service locator but set_feature injects MyLogger at the start of application, this is a good link between differences http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection

Comment: Unfortunately this is a Service Locator. And [Service Locator is an antipattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`dependencies` package](https://proofit404.github.io/dependencies/) to achieve your goal.

Comment: Link seems to be dead.